# Check if specific cell has been updated excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm looking for an excel formula, or VBA macro rolled into a UDF (user defined function) which effectively checks whether Enter/Return has been pressed in a particular cell.

I happen to have iterative calculations turned on meaning that if I want to see whether the value in a cell has changed (in this example, *H11*), I can have code in *I11* like: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(I11),I11=0),H11,I11)` Without returning a circular reference. I then compare the value in *H11* to the one stored in *I11*, if they are different then *H11* has changed

However my problem is that I need to know if H11 has been updated at all, so the value in H11 may not have changed but I could've gone into H11, typed the same thing and pressed enter, and I need to know if that happens!

I hope that's clear-ish, I'm thinking `Cell('address')` (with no reference) could be used to show whether H11 was the last cell edited, but the problem is, H11 may already be the last cell edited, so I can't get my head around it.

I haven't touched VBA yet 'cos I don't know how, but if anyone finds a solution using that or normal formulae I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks!

Comment: the Worksheet_Change event could be useful for you, but I don't fully understand your question so applying it might be difficult/unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the below code in your worksheet VBA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("H11")) Is Nothing) Then
        'do you coding here
    End If
End Sub
```